# PrimeFaces Accordion panel keyboard focus on current tab command button

Tags: primefaces

I have an accordion panel with few tabs with in a form . Each tab has a command button (I use the update and process attributes to process specific inputs with a tab). I have set the multiple attribute to true on the accordion panel. When the page initially loads  the first tab is open by default. If i hit the enter key on the key board then the command button in the first tab has the keyboard focus and the fields are processed. now I leave the first tab open and open another tab and i hit the enter key the keyboard focus is still on the command button on the first tab . I tried using the p:focus with for/context attributes but with no help.

```
<h:form id="calculatorsNTools">
<p:accordionPanel multiple="true">
    <p:tab title="Teenage Check">
        <h:inputText id="age1" required="true" label="Age"
            value="#{calculatorBacking.age}" validatorMessage="Enter a value">
            <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="1" />
        </h:inputText>
        <p:message for="age1" id="msgage1" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="gridTAresult">
            <p:commandButton id="calculateTA"
                action="#{calculatorBacking.calculateTA}" value="Calculate"
                process="@this,age1"
                update="gridTAresult">
            </p:commandButton>
            <b> Teenage (y/n)</b>
            <h:outputLabel id="resultTA" value="#{calculatorBacking.resultTeenAge}"></h:outputLabel>
        </h:panelGrid>
         </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Retirement Check">
            <h:inputText id="age2" required="true" label="Age"
                value="#{calculatorBacking.age}" validatorMessage="Enter a value">
                <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="1" />
            </h:inputText>
            <p:message for="age2" id="msgage2" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="gridREresult">
                <p:commandButton id="calculateRE"
                    action="#{calculatorBacking.calculateRE}" value="Calculate"
                    process="@this,age2"
                    update="gridREresult">
                </p:commandButton>
                <b> Retirement (y/n)</b>
                <h:outputLabel id="resultRE" value="#{calculatorBacking.resultRetirement}"></h:outputLabel>
            </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
<h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to accomplish what you want. I am not completely sure how to do it on an accordion but on a tabView it would be:

```
<p:tabView onTabChange="handleTabChange(event, index)">
```

Then create a javascript function to set the focus:

```
function handleTabChange(event, index){
    if(index == 1){
        var opControl = document.getElementById("calculatorsNTools:calculateTA");
        opControl.focus();

    }
}
```

You should be able to modify that to what you need for the accordionPanel.

Comment: I used the onTabChange attribute on the accordion panel and tried the code above, and the accordion panel would stop working altogether.

Comment: Yeah, the above is for a tabview. The PrimeFaces documentation shows the tabView passing (event, index) while an Accordion passes (panel). I don't know how you get the index information from the panel object passed to the js function.

Comment: I solved this problem by creating seperate forms for each tab, thank you Steve